# Search for user files in relative and absolute path

Tags: bash, search, shell, directory

I have cript which search for user files in absolute path, but now I need to add for relative also.  How can I do this?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
        DIR=$1
        USERNAME=$2
        while [ ! $(id -g $USERNAME) ]; do
                echo "non-existing username, please add again "
                read USERNAME
        done
        while [ ! -d "/home/$DIR" ]; do

                echo "non-existing '$DIR' directory, please add again "
                read DIR
        done
        echo "variable username is now $USERNAME"
        echo "variable DIR is now $DIR"
        echo -e "username group   file"
        ls -1Apl /home/$DIR | grep -v /\$ | awk -v user=${USERNAME} '$3==user{print}{}' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f3 -f4 -f9
else
        echo "bla"
fi
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using `find` for this?

Comment: For your relative paths, what do you want them to be relative against, the current working directory or something else?

Comment: if i put: directory username it should act as relative, if i put: /dir/dir1 username it should act as absolute.

Comment: Please don't parse `ls`. [Here's why](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). As to your question, here's a hint: if the directory doesn't begin with a slash, it's relative.

Answer (score 1):

i don't need damn abolute and relative path with freakin' ls :/
so

```
while [ ! -d "$DIR" ]; do
```

and

```
ls -1Apl $DIR | grep -v /\$
```

and it is working